# Flatten/Reduce nested JSON based on paths, collecting fields in path/hierarchy

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

UPDATE: 11/18/18: I've added more examples and clarification to the end of this post.

I have nested JSON structures, resulting from Elasticsearch aggregations, that look similar to this (simplified for the example):

```
{
"some_field": "ignore",
"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "a",
    "buckets": [
      { "key": "foo", "name": "FOO" },
      { "key": "bar", "name": "BAR" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "b",
    "buckets": [
      { "key": "boo", "name": "BOO" },
      { "key": "baa", "name": "BAA" }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

I would like to convert it to

```
[ 
    {key: "a", name: "FOO"},
    {key: "a", name: "FOO"},
    {key: "b", name: "BOO"},
    {key: "b", name: "BAA"}
]
```

While this is a simple problem for any specific case, I don't want to "re-invent the wheel" and code for it each time. The level of nesting can vary and the fields I might pick (along the path) can vary.

The above is somewhat simplified example. As these come from Elasticsearch responses, another example might be:

```
"aggregations": {
"boo": {
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "keyA",
      "foo": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "keyA.a",
            "bar": {
              "hits": {
                "hits": [{"_index": "indexA", "_id": "idA", "_source": {"name": "nameA"}}]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "keyB",
      "foo": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "keyA.a",
            "bar": {
              "hits": {
                "hits": [{"_index": "indexB", "_id": "idB", "_source": {"name": "nameB"}}]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}

and my desired result, for flatten/picking fields is

```
[
{"boo": "keyA", "foo": "keyA.a", "name": "nameA", "id": "idA"},
{"boo": "keyB", "foo": "keyA.a", "name": "name", "id": "idB"}
]
```

Does anyone know of a way to do with JMESPath, JSONPath, lodash, etc? With something like JSONPath or JMESPath, I can select the "leaf" value easily, but I am trying to collect fields along the path, in the hierachy.

As noted, I could code each case, but I'd like to reuse a library and declare my projection.

I think I could do this with jq, but I need it to run in a browser.

Thanks

Comment: _The level of nesting can vary and the fields I might pick (along the path) can vary_. This makes your question hard to answer. Could you please provide the exact input/output you're expecting, along with the expected variations? It's hard to answer otherwise.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb, I updated the original to add a more detailed example of my need. I am mostly looking for a library that might provide a general solution to this type of problem. I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Please read the text that goes with the `json` tag... especially the part that is emphasised.

Comment: I can't see a way to write one piece of code that produces the required output for the given inputs. Maybe somebody else can. Hope you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lodash is useful in your case and can be used in a browser.
[flapMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) and [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) functions are what you need.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
var obj = {
  "some_field": "ignore",
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "a",
      "buckets": [
        { "key": "foo", "name": "FOO" },
        { "key": "bar", "name": "BAR" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "b",
      "buckets": [
        { "key": "boo", "name": "BOO" },
        { "key": "baa", "name": "BAA" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var res = _.flatMap(obj.buckets, x => {
  return _.map(x.buckets, y => {
    y.key = x.key;
    return y;
  });
});

console.log(res);
//  Output:
//  [ { key: 'a', name: 'FOO' },
//    { key: 'a', name: 'BAR' },
//    { key: 'b', name: 'BOO' },
//    { key: 'b', name: 'BAA' }]
```